# How to attach a image and a .txt(multiple files) file to gmail through Coding?

Tags: android, gmail, uri, email-attachments

I am trying to attach an image file and .txt file but only one file is attaching one is not attaching how to attach both the files. 
if i use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` then the app gets force close.

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
public static Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email,
        String subject, String body, String fileName) {


    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Explicitly only use Gmail to send
    emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
            "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

    emailIntent.setType("*/*");

    // Add the recipients
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            new String[] { email }
            );

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    // Add the attachment by specifying a reference to our custom
    // ContentProvider
    // and the specific file of interest
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/"+ "anything.txt"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/"+ "anything.jpg"));

    return emailIntent;
}
```

If I put a .jpg file at last before return it is attaching. But if I put a .txt file at last then it is attaching. I want to attach both files pls help.

Comment: if i use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE then the app gets force close. Show us the logcat. You have to use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE for attaching multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the code below and change file path's to your files.

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Medplann/IMG.jpg"))); // Add your image URIs here
imageUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Medplann/Report.pdf")));

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

---

Read this page : [send](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)